# how to convert a date into string in plsql?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, plsql

how I'm going to convert the date into string ? my database is plsql and the date was insert from basic date picker which i assign as bdp1.

```
select * from smsdw.lot_act where (tran_dttm <= to_date('4/20/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and tran_dttm > to_date('4/19/2012' ,'MM/DD/YYYY'))
```

Comment: my input that i key-in from basic date picker is read as date not a string, but in my db is in string, so i need to convert my input as string.

Comment: Your query is correct. What's the problem?

Comment: if i want to search the date '4/19/2012' yes, i can get the result. but if i want to rephrase it as parameter i can't. this is query from oracle.

Comment: Why is your date stored as a string in your database?  If it were stored as a date, you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your format and your string don't agree.

You need a 0 in front of the 4, like this: `04/20/2012`.

<strike>Or you need to adjust your format, like this: `M/D/YYYY`</strike>
On second look, the [`to_date()` documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) doesn't show support for the single `M`. You need to include the leading 0 with your month, and a single `D` for the day would be extremely foolish.

---

An update based on your comment. Let me lead, though, by saying that using string concatenation to substitute data into queries like this is **evil** and likely to lead your app being hacked.

```vb
Dim queryString As String = "select * from smsdw.lot_act where (tran_dttm <= to_date( '" & bdp1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "','MM/DD/YYYY') and tran_dttm > to_date( '" & bdp1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')"
```

As a bonus, doing this the *right* away avoids the need to worry about date formats at all:

```
Dim queryString As String = "select * from smsdw.lot_act where tran_dttm <= :bdp1 and tran_dttm > :bdp1 "

command.Parameters.Add(":bdp1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = bdp1
```

But again: different libraries may handle this slightly different. Some require the `:` character, some don't allow it, and some work on the order, rather than the name (meaning you would need to add the parameter twice).

Comment: ok i'm try to convert like this but its doesn't work >>

Dim queryString As String = "select * from smsdw.lot_act where (tran_dttm <= to_date( '" & bdp1.Month & "/" & bdp1.Date & "/" & bdp1.Year & "/,'DD/MM/YYYY') and tran_dttm > to_date( '" & bdp1 & "' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')

Comment: @Husna5207 that code is vulnerable to sql injection. It's practically begging to get hacked. Time to read up on query parameters/prepared statements.

Comment: Also: you just swapped month and day, which wasn't what I suggested at all. This does nothing to add a leading 0.

Comment: The correct way to handle this depends on the context, and how you submit that the string to the db server... but google for parameterized queries or prepared statements.

Comment: +1 - Parameterised query is the way to go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930170/easier-way-to-send-parameterised-query-to-database